# Prompt Box for Cell Value which is >20% OR < -20%

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and need assistance in some basic code if any of you could be so kind.

I am trying to create a Msgbox to populate when a calculation in a given cell is >20% OR <-20%.

I can get a Msgbox to populate when a value is >20%, for example 36%. But when I try and get the code to do the same for <-20%, for example -49%, then the prompt box won't load. I have tried multiple variations of the code without much luck.

THIS WORKS FINE:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range, Rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rg = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("P27"))
    If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
        For Each xCell In Rg
            If xCell.Value >= "0.2" Then
                VBA.MsgBox "You have exceeded the reportable reconciliation limit of +/- 20%." & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Please email sales@XXXX " _
                           , vbOKOnly, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

THIS DOES NOTHING:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range, Rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rg = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("P27"))
    If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
        For Each xCell In Rg
            If xCell.Value <= "-0.2" Then        'This part is not executed properly
                VBA.MsgBox "You have exceeded the reportable reconciliation limit of +/- 20%." & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Please email sales@XXXX " _
                           , vbOKOnly, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

In fact, when I try and use the code for anything <20, i.e. `If xCell.Value <= "-0.2"`, then the Msgbox does not populate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string value instead of numeric, try `If xCell.Value <= -0.2 Then` instead.
Also, you can combine both statements in and ifelse statement:

```
If xCell.Value >= 0.2 Then
        VBA.MsgBox "You have exceeded the reportable reconciliation limit of +/- 20%." & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Please email sales@XXXX " _
, vbOKOnly, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE"
ElseIf xCell.Value <= -0.2 Then
        VBA.MsgBox "You have exceeded the reportable reconciliation limit of +/- 20%." & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Please email sales@XXXX " _
, vbOKOnly, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE"
End if
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.